# How to set adjustment layer to folder layer using Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know how to set adjustment layer to folder in Photoshop CS6 and higher but how to do this using CS5 version?
It's possible to set it to layer only.

Comment: Do you possibly mean **Layer Styles**? You can't apply layer styles to folders in CS5... it requires CS6 or better.

Comment: Hi sqbany, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Not Layer Styles but adjustment layers (levels, saturation, contrast etc.). In Photoshop **CS6** it's possible to clip __levels__ to the folder (group of layers).
To clip adjustment layer in Photoshop CS6 the mouse cursor should be over the space between adjustment layers and folder.
I think In Photoshop **CS5** this function doesn't exist. My question is - is there a way to clip adjustment layer to **more than one** layer using **Photoshop CS5**?